# Can't click on links with div in the way

Tags: html, css

I can't click on my links anywhere. They are not inside of the div that seems to be blocking my ability to click on them. They are also not supposed to be opaque because they are not inside of that div. They are in their own divs. Anyone see what I'm missing here? How do I change this so that I can click on my links again? I was messing with the background image for awhile. I just don't know what's going on. This is my cheezy website I'm making for school. I just need help so I can turn this in! Thank you!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--

LOCAL PAGE
Heather M Smith
My First Home Page
CSIS 1430
6/18/2017


-->

<html>

<head>
    <title>Heather's Home Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
        body
        {
            max-height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }



        #background{
            background: #373737 url('pinkBackground.jpg') no-repeat;
            min-height: 100%;
            min-width: 1024px;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: -3;
        }

        #heading
        {
            text-align: center;
        }

        #emailAddressLink
        {
            color: white;
        }

        #topBox
        {
            margin-top: 50px;
        }

        h1, h2, h3, h4
        {
            color: black; 
            font-family: Georgia;
            text-shadow: 1px 0px 5px white;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 4;
        }

        ol, ul, li
        {
            color: black; 
            font-family: Georgia; 
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 2em;
            z-index: 4;

        }


        .bigText
        {
            color: #373737; 
            font-family: Georgia;
            font-size: 60px;
        }

        .link
        {
            color: #5200cc;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: Georgia;
            font-size: 25px;
            word-spacing: 5px;
            line-height: 2em;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-shadow: 2px 0px 10px #ffff99;
            z-index: 4;

        }


        .box
        {
            background-color: #DCD0C0;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 2px solid #373737;
            margin: 10px auto;
            width: 800px;
            height: 300px;
            opacity: .3;
            z-index: -3;

        }

        .boxContents
        {
            width: 800px;
            height: 340px;
            margin: 10px auto;
            margin-top: -350px;
            text-align: left;
            line-height: 2em;
            z-index: 4;
        }

        #intro
        {
          font-family: Georgia;
          font-size: medium; 
          word-wrap: normal;
          font-size: 1.5em;
        }

        #slccLogo
        {
            position: relative;
            float: right;
            padding: 30px;
            width: 250px;
            height: 250px;
        }

        #owlImage
        {
            float: right;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
        }

        #lastBox
        {
           line-height: 6em;

        }




    </style>
</head>

<body>
<!--BACKGROUND-->
    <div id="background"></div>
    <!--HEADING-->
      <div id="heading">
        <h1 class='bigText'>Heather's Home Page</h1>
        <h2>CSIS 1430 | Email me:</h2>
        <!--EMAIL ADDRESS-->
        <address>
            <a class='link' id="emailAddressLink" 
href="mailto:HeatherSmithx@gmail.com" target="_blank">
                Heather's Email
            </a>
        </address>
      </div>

    <br>
    <!--BACKGROUND DIV BOX-->
    <div class='box' id="topBox"></div>
    <!--INTRO-->
    <div class="boxContents">
            <span id="intro">Hello! I'm Heather, a student at 
            <a class='link' href="http://www.slcc.edu/">Salt Lake Community 
College</a>
            studying Computer Science. I want to be a software developer and 
my goal 
            is to get an internship before I graduate. I'm getting some 
experience at
            Century Link, where I currently work. I have worked at Century 
Link for
            two years as a Repair Representative. Even though my interest
            in computers is great, I'm also an aspiring artist.
            <br>
            I've been painting, drawing, and playing music for most of my 
life
            and I know there's always so much more to learn. I'm hoping to 
use my 
            creativity in a way that can be applied to developing software 
in the
            future.
            </span>
    </div>


 <br>
 <!--COMPUTER SCIENCE COURSES-->
 <div class='box'></div> 
    <div class="boxContents">
        <h2 class="heading">My Computer Science Courses at <a class='link' 
href="http://www.slcc.edu/" target="_blank">SLCC</a></h2>
        <img id="slccLogo" src="SLCCLogo.png" alt="SLCC">
        <ul>
            <li class="link"><a href = 
"https://heathersmithx.wordpress.com/computer-science-and-information-
systems">CSIS 1030</a></li>
            <li>CSIS 1340 - content coming soon</li>
            <li>CSIS 1400 - content coming soon</li>
            <li>CSIS 1410 - content coming soon</li>
            <li>CSIS 1430 - content coming soon</li>
            <li>CSIS 1550 - content coming soon</li>

        </ul>
    </div>

<br>
<!--GENERAL EDUCATION COURSES-->
<div class='box'></div>
    <div class="boxContents">
        <h2>My General Education Courses at <a class='link' 
href="http://www.slcc.edu/" target="_blank">SLCC</a></h2>
        <img id="owlImage" src="Owl.png" alt="Wise Owl">
        <ul>

            <li class="link"><a 
href="https://heathersmithx.wordpress.com/coursework/english-2010/">ENGLISH 
2010 NOTEBOOKS</a></li>
            <li class="link"><a href = 
"https://heathersmithx.wordpress.com/coursework/film-culture/686-2/">FILM 
 1070 FINAL PAPER</a></li>
            <li class="link"><a href="index/reflection.html">CSIS 1430 
REFLECTION</a></li>
            <li class="link"><a 
href="https://heathersmithx.wordpress.com/outside-the-classroom/">OUTSIDE OF 
SCHOOL...</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>

<br>
<!--MY FAVORITE WEBSITES-->
<div class='box'></div>
    <div class="boxContents">
        <h2>My Favorite Web Sites!</h2>
        <ol>
            <li class='link'><a href = "http://www.dreamincode.net/" 
target="_blank">Dream in Code</a></li>
            <li class='link'><a href = "https://www.wolframalpha.com/" 
target="_blank">Wolfram Alpha</a></li>
            <li class='link'><a href = "https://slcc.instructure.com/" 
target="_blank">SLCC Canvas</a></li>
            <li class='link'><a href = "https://www.w3schools.com/" 
target="_blank">w3schools</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>

<br>
<!--PROJECTS FROM THIS CLASS-->
<div class='box'></div>

  <div class="boxContents" id="lastBox">
    <h2>Projects from CSIS 1430</h2>
        <h4 class="link">
            <a class='link' href='resume.html' target="_blank">RESUME | </a>
            <a class='link' href='littleBoxes/littleBoxes.html' 
target="_blank">LITTLE BOXES | </a>
            <a class="link" href='map/utahMap.html' target='blank'>IMAGE MAP 
|</a>
            <a class="link" href='PizzaPlace/pizzaIndex.html' 
target='blank'>PIZZA ORDER FORM |</a>
            <a class='link' href='GuessingGame/GuessIndex.html' 
target="_blank">GUESSING GAME | </a>
            <a class='link' href='TicTacToe/TicTacToe.html' 
target="_blank">TIC TAC TOE | </a>
            <a class='link' href='index/reflection.html' 
target="_blank">REFLECTION </a>
        </h4>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change the class `.link` to have `z-index:5;` and then test it.

Comment: I removed the opacity and that made my links clickable within the divs. So I just decided to go without a background and put a border around it with a box-shadow. Similar effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the `.boxContents` class. The `margin-top` selector is pulling everything off. If you remove it, your links should function as expected. Also, just on a side-note, it's worth avoiding using lots of z-indexes in your CSS if they aren't required. It can lead to issues and content being hidden all too easily.

Comment: That makes the links work, but then how to I position my divs to be inside of the other box, while making the links still clickable? Is there another way I can move my box contents back up into the box?

Comment: This just gives me another problem. I still have to put the contents into the box.

Comment: You need to re-address your CSS selectors. In this case, I would remove the .boxContents class from the div containers they are set on. Instead, simply wrap the content in a basic <div> element and nest it inside the <div class="box"> element like so - <div class='box'>
    <div>
        <h2 class="heading">My Computer Science Courses at </h2>
    </div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot of z-index action going on there. I would be careful about how you are using the z-index. Refer to this great article on the CSS z-index which also higlights some of the pitfalls of using z-index. https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out. I did delete all of the z-indexes except for the background one.

Comment: Can you edit your original question and post the new HTML and CSS or create a jsfiddle with your code and we can help you figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class `.link` to have `z-index:5;` and then test it. It will put it in front of your other `<divs>`.

Just make sure you keep that class with a higher `z-index` than your other classes / IDs.

Comment: Remove z-index from everything and put your contents of the ID `#Background` within `body`.